# Open redirected link in a new tab using custom field in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have used a custom field called `redirect` in Woocommerce  product single page and this makes it redirect to a link other than the single product page link. However, I want to open that redirected link in a new tab. My followed solution opens that link in the same window.

The code I followed:

```
<?php
global $post; // < -- globalize, just in case
$field = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'redirect', true);
if($field) wp_redirect(clean_url($field), 301);
get_header();
?>
```

Source: [nathanrice.net](http://www.nathanrice.net/blog/how-to-redirect-a-page-using-custom-fields-in-wordpress/)

Comment: With redirect you cannot redirect to new tab. Just find the link in templates and add a `target="_blank"` tag

Comment: Yeah I knew this and that's why I am looking for an alternative to this solution. As you stated to edit template file and add _blank to that link but this is done by a custom field and I do not find a file to edit and place that _blank. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Nop, its not possible at all with wp_redirect(). You can use java script or other methods to do it.

Comment: Thanks.. Any suggestion in this case?

Comment: try to use javascript. You can call javascript function on load or ready event. Use window.open() to open new url.